# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to run a python project that I have not written myself. This has required me to install a series of new libraries, but more importantly, it has required me to install Cython.

I think I've installed Cython succesfully at this point. I am using MinGW for my compiler. When I try to run the project I get the error

```
ImportError: Building module RayTrace failed: ['DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat\n']
```

As far as I've understood this is about setting the path for the compiler. I have created the distutils.cfg file that says MinGW is the compiler as well as put MinGW in Path.

Where do I go from here?

```
this is the complete traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marten\Python\DisperseIt\DisperseIt.py", line 5, in <module>
    from DisperseProjectDisperseCtrlFrame import *
  File "C:\Users\Marten\Python\DisperseIt\DisperseProjectDisperseCtrlFrame.py", line 12, in <module>
    import SectionCalc
  File "C:\Users\Marten\Python\DisperseIt\SectionCalc.py", line 10, in <module>
    from RayTrace import CalcIndices
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cython-0.20.2-py2.7-win32.egg\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 431, in load_module
    language_level=self.language_level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cython-0.20.2-py2.7-win32.egg\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 209, in load_module
    inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cython-0.20.2-py2.7-win32.egg\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 186, in build_module
    reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cython-0.20.2-py2.7-win32.egg\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 104, in pyx_to_dll
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cython-0.20.2-py2.7-win32.egg\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 163, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 337, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cython-0.20.2-py2.7-win32.egg\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 171, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 496, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 271, in query_vcvarsall
    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
ImportError: Building module RayTrace failed: ['DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat\n']
```

Comment: what does distutils.cfg look like?

Comment: IT reads, in it's entirety:

[build]
compiler = mingw32

Comment: try `[build_ext] 
compiler = mingw32`

Comment: This worked, now it crashes in a different manner!

Comment: what happens now? You have both `[build_ext]  compiler = mingw32` and `[build] 
compiler = mingw32 
` in distutils.cfg?

Comment: Should I have both? I changed [build] to [build_ext].

What happens now is that it comes to the file cygwincompiler.py where it stops with the error "ImportError: Building module RayTrace failed: ["CompileError: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory\n"]". Not finding gcc was a problem when I was installing Cython too, but thought I solved it.

Comment: as far as I know you need both. What was the error using just `[build_ext]  compiler = mingw32` ?

Comment: I tried including both, but I still get the same error as when I only write [build_ext], which is abovementioned "ImportError: Building module RayTrace failed: ["CompileError: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory\n"]". What is the difference between [build] and [build_ext] anyway?

Comment: Answer by @PadraicCunningham worked for me - I think for it to work you need to have mingw binaries folder in your path. In my instance I have mingw64 installed I can just call gcc in the cmd window for it to be executed.